# php exec() secure

Tags: php, python, exec

I'm trying to execute a py file from php.
here is my code:

```
//usage python my.py var1 var2
$libre = 'python ../../../../root/py/my.py '.$var1.' '.$var2.'';
$cleanlibre = escapeshellarg($libre);
echo exec($cleanlibre);
```

What is wrong?
Why is it returning nothing?

I also need to know how to secure exec well. Thanks.

--edit--

Used passthru

```
$libre = 'python ../../../../root/py/mech.py '.$var1.' '.$var2.'';
$cleanlibre = escapeshellarg($libre);
passthru($cleanlibre, $result);
echo $result;
//returned 127 <- i don't know where thats from.
```

Comment: Well `exec` only returns the last line of output. Are you sure you do not want to use `passthru`? Also, did you try running the command you are showing into exec on the command line to make sure the syntax is correct?

Comment: @thatidiotguy do i just change exec to passthru? I now have a working exec code.

Comment: Also, don't post the answer to your own question in the bottom of the question, make a new answer with the answer and check mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`escapeshellarg` shall only be used to escape the arguments, not the whole command.

```
//usage python my.py var1 var2
$libre = 'python ../../../../root/py/my.py '.escapeshellarg($var1).' '.escapeshellarg($var2).'';
echo exec($libre );
```

Answer (score 0):

exec return result in second argument of function, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: You still get last line of output as specified by documentation.

Comment: If the output argument is present, then the specified array will be filled with "every line" of output from the command